# How to sort elasticsearch buckets by timestamp BEFORE results are filtered?

Tags: elasticsearch

my use case is as follows:

I have documents on elasticsearch, I save some telemetry data and i'm aggregating it before ingesting it to elastic search (each document can have a count field that tells how many times this event occurred).

Example of a json field:

```
{
   "timestamp": "2021-06-05T06:53:25.275172"
   "count": 5
   "name": "myname",
   "type: "mytype",
   "sub_type": "mysubtype"
},
{
   "timestamp": "2021-05-05T07:53:25.275172"
   "count": 2
   "name": "myname",
   "type: "mytype",
   "sub_type": "zzzzzmysubtype222"
}
{
   "timestamp": "2021-04-05T06:22:25.275172"
   "count": 1
   "name": "myname",
   "type: "mytype",
   "sub_type": "mysubtype"
},
```

I'm doing a query to aggregate all "unique" documents (by name, type and sub_type), while counting the total number of responses, and i want to sort the buckets by **timestamp**.

The thing is, i have a "limit" parameter that limits the number of results received, and when i limit it by 1, i don't get the latest event bucket (as i understand it sorts them by the 3 fields, then limits the size, and only then sorts it.

So, when running the below query - i would want to get the "myname, mytype, mysubtype", but i actually get the "myname, mytype, zzzzzmysubtype222" as the first bucket.
If i increase the limit - then it's sorted correctly.

This is my query:

```
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [{"range": {"timestamp": {"lte": "now", "gte": "2020-06-05"}}}],
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "events": {
                "composite": {
                    "size": 1,    <----------- this doesn't give me latest bucket
                    "sources": [
                        {"name": {"terms": {"field": "name.keyword"}}},
                        {"type": {"terms": {"field": "type.keyword"}}},
                        {"sub_type": {"terms": {"field": "sub_type.keyword"}}},
                    ],
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "events_count": {"sum": {"field": "count"}},
                    "latest_event": {"top_hits": {"sort": [{"timestamp": {"order": "desc"}}], "size": 1}},
                    "top_hit": {"max": {"field": "timestamp"}},
                    "events_bucket_sort": {"bucket_sort": {"sort": [{"top_hit": {"order": "desc"}}]}},
                },
            }
        },
        "size": 0,
    }
```

So, what i'm trying to do is to sort the buckets by the latest event timestamp (top_hit) - any help would be appreciated.

I think it's related to this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_order

But timestamp shouldn't be aggregated so how do i control the natural sort of the buckets? I need only the newest ones to be received first, no matter the size,

If it's not possible, any way to get those unique documents aggregation that share several common fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand your question, you need to have the unique buckets based on the `name`, `type`, and `sub_type` field, and then based on the buckets formed you need to get the latest bucket(based on the timestamp).

If you want to get unique buckets based on multiple fields, you can use [multi terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/7.12/search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation.html) along with the top_hits aggregation to get the latest bucket based on the timestamp

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "genres_and_products": {
      "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [
          {
            "field": "name.keyword"
          },
          {
            "field": "type.keyword"
          },
          {
            "field": "sub_type.keyword"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "latest_event": {
      "top_hits": {
        "sort": [
          {
            "timestamp": {
              "order": "desc"
            }
          }
        ],
        "size": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "genres_and_products": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": [
            "myname",
            "mytype",
            "mysubtype"
          ],
          "key_as_string": "myname|mytype|mysubtype",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": [
            "myname",
            "mytype",
            "zzzzzmysubtype222"
          ],
          "key_as_string": "myname|mytype|zzzzzmysubtype222",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "latest_event": {
      "hits": {
        "total": {
          "value": 3,
          "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "67775188",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              "timestamp": "2021-06-05T06:53:25.275172",
              "count": 5,
              "name": "myname",
              "type": "mytype",
              "sub_type": "mysubtype"
            },
            "sort": [
              1622876005275
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, yet - not yet supported on AWS elasticsearch - but i can wait, does it sort it before the size filter is applied? (i think that yes, according to your result).

Comment: @ArielB multi terms aggregation was introduced in elasticsearch version 7.12. And, yes sort is applied before the size.

Comment: of course, hopefully it will be introduced also in AWS as i see it's a part of xpack.
Thanks!